# How to shorten the Python code? Part II

Tags: code-golf, math, tips, python

Code [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 245 bytes

```python
E=print
def F():
	B,C,A=1,1,1;yield 0
	while True:yield B;B,C,A=B+C+A+1,C+A+1,A+1
C=int(input())
D=0
for A in range(C):
	E(end='*'*(C-(C-A)+1));B=A
	while 0<B:E(end=' '+chr(42+B)*B);B-=1
	E();D+=1
for A in F():
	if D==0:E(end=str(A));break
	D-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9LDoIwEIbX9BTd0VJIQN0IzqIPPIEXQCnSSAqpEMPpsQQ088hk8v/fZIZ5bHt7XJYSBmfsiGrd4CuhOQpELGMOWeyjmI3uapyi4NOaTuObm3S@7USx6QSTjLMs3rovJMHziLHDNBJKkYIUNb3DHBuLXWWfmsj1TEm0rSGMwojIxCenLKO0EMB/19KLyHcVDtmjdeR0YIJGwqsSyFYELRTz05@/fWAarADS3fweHeGefHe6eqFAeeuynL8)

### What it does?

Takes a number from input, loops from 0 to \$x - 1\$ (let's call iterator \$y\$), prints ASCII 41 ("*"),  \$y\$ times with a space and prints ASCII 42, \$y - 1\$ times with a space and repeat until the \$y - x\$ is \$0\$, print a newline and go to next iteration.

If the loop is ended, print the total of the output (not including the output of spaces and newlines).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 106 bytes

```python
C=int(input())
i=0
while i<C:i+=1;print(*[j*chr(42+j%i)for j in range(i,0,-1)])
print(C*~C*~-~C//6,end='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39k2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTK9PWgKs8IzMnVSHTxtkqU9vW0LqgCKRCKzpLKzmjSMPESDtLNVMzLb9IIUshM0@hKDEvPVUjU8dAR9dQM1aTC6LaWasOiHTrnPX1zXRS81Js1dU1//@3BAA)

The grand total can be computed as `C*(C+1)*(C+2)//6` (see [tetrahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number)). So you don't need `F` at all! This saves a lot of bytes.

This formula can be golfed down to `C*-~C*-~-~C//6`, and then further to `C*~C*~-~C//6` because two of the `-`s cancel out in the product.

Then, I just wrote some simpler code to print the ASCII characters. Usually when you want output separated by spaces, `print(*[list comprehension])` is pretty good, so I tried that.

The clever thing here is using `j%i` to count like `0, i-1, i-2, ... 1` on each row. Try replacing it with just `j` and compare the output.

There are only two print calls now, so `E=print` doesn't save bytes anymore.

`print(end=str(num))` is longer than `print(num,end='')`.

### Tiny golfs in your code

- `B,C,A=1,1,1` can be `B=C=A=1`.
- `while True` can be `while 1`.
- `(C-(C-A)+1)` equals `(A+1)` equals `-~A`.
- `while 0<B` can be `while B` here.

Making a generator and extracting the `D`-th value seems painful. You can "inline" the iterator: delete the definition of `F` and just perform the logic inside `F`, `D` times at the end of your code:

```python
E=print
C=int(input())
D=0
for A in range(C):
    E(end='*'*-~A);B=A
    while B:E(end=' '+chr(42+B)*B);B-=1
    E();D+=1
b=c=a=0
while D:b,c,a=b+c+a+1,c+a+1,a+1;D-=1
print(b,end='')
```

If we stare at the assignments long enough, we can figure out that `b,c,a=b+c+a+1,c+a+1,a+1` can be `a+=1;c+=a;b+=c`.

Also, we count up from `D=0` to `D=C`, so we can just use `C` instead of `D`:

```py
E=print
C=int(input())
for A in range(C):
    E(end='*'*-~A);B=A
    while B:E(end=' '+chr(42+B)*B);B-=1
    E()
b=c=a=0
while C:a+=1;c+=a;b+=c;C-=1
print(b,end='')
```

But an even shorter way to just repeat some code `C` times is this:

```py
exec("a+=1;c+=a;b+=c;"*C)
```

Of course, the tetrahedral number formula is even shorter than any of this.

Comment: `for` instead of `while` saves another byte - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39k2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1nTqqAIpEArOksrOaNIw8RIO0s1UxOkLAuhLFPHQEfXUDNWkwui2lmrDoh065z19c10UvNSbNXVNf//twQA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @emanresuA That outputs a stray newline at the front, and is missing a line at the end. It would need to be `range(1,C+1)`.

Comment: +1 This answers me.

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure to check out Lynn's answer. It contains some great advice too.*

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 237 bytes

```python
E=print
def F():
 B=C=A=1;yield 0
 while 1:yield B;B,C,A=B+C+A+1,C+A+1,A+1
C=int(input())
D=0
for A in range(C):
 E(end='*'*(C-(C-A)+1));B=A
 while 0<B:E(end=' '+chr(42+B)*B);B-=1
 E();D+=1
for A in F():
 if D<1:E(end=str(A));break
 D-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dDoIwDIXv9xS9Y2OQMH9ugF5sA99DZcgiGWRiDE@PI6BJ25w053ztOE/d4I7LUuPorZtIY1q4UJYTUKhRoihma/oGMgKfzvYGRL4tVKESnUhUXHPJRbLN0ERjAFHrxvdEGSMVZqQdPEiwDvzVPQzVK7@mxjUYxVFMdRpKMi4YKxTK36msVPnugojfO09PB65YrIIrRbEiWFHxoP787XXbQlWKPfuaPJUBfPPm@iRQheSynL8)

My go at this. Will keep golfing later.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NDoIwEIX3PcXsaCkk1J8NMIu24Am8gEqRRlJIhRhOjzWoycxkMnnvezMuUze4/brWOHrrJtKYFk6U5QQUapQoisWavoGMwKuzvYGzn02@3VShEp1IVFxzyUWyzdBEY2BR68Z5ooyRCjPSDh4kWAf@4u6G6k9ETY1rMIqjmOo0lGRcMFYolL@0rFT5VwURv3WeHnZcsVgFVYrig2BFxcP252/f2xaqUny9z8lTGcBXby4PAlVwruvxDQ)

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3, 132 bytes**

Here is my approach to this problem.

```
C=int(input())
print(*(' '.join(['*'*(A+1)]+[B*chr(42+B)for B in range(A,0,-1)])for A in range(C)),C*(C+1)*(C+2)//6,sep='\n',end='')
```

Please refer to Lynn's answer for more details and for a much shorter code. For example, my code could be further optimized by replacing `C*(C+1)*(C+2)//6` with `C*~C*~-~C//6`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYsxEsIgEEV7T0G3u4BGY7SjAI4RLRxFg8XCIBaeHhMbmzfz3/yXP3VKvG/Nm8gVI@d3RaJVLsuUCAI2zxQZR5Ag0aodndXo5HUqOPTK0T0V4URkUS78CGj1Vq/nz8/bv/dE2kv0c7@wp6476lfIBk4MOvDNAFBrhy8)